# Should "reference-request" explicitly forbid asking for solution manuals?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-wikis

I've seen a few requests for solution manuals recently using the reference-request tag, and while I didn't like seeing such questions, I could see why someone would see using that tag as justified (though I would argue that a reference request would be for a general source about some subject, rather than asking if a specific solution manual exists and is available online). There has been [past discussion](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11323/are-questions-about-existence-of-a-solution-manual-to-a-book-allowed-on-mse) where it seems like the consensus is that such questions are not allowed, so if this is still the consensus held by users, should the tag be edited to explicitly state this?

Comment: A user can search Google using the title of their text, and if there is a *published* and licensed solution manual that corresponds to that specific text, they will find it immediately, no need to go to MSE to find it.  If there is some pirated, or private attempt to collect solutions, to circulate, then they can find it on there own.  MSE is not in the business of searching for clandestine sources of solutions/solution manuals.  Anything above board can be found by the asker via Google.  Let's not "GIFT" (google it for them).

Comment: Obviously, I agree with the past discussion you cite.  I don't know whether the reference tag should be modified to include each "exception", because there are also requests students post for say, a reference or text on, say, to cover a student's  first semester linear algebra, application oriented, and that *includes some exercises with solutions.*  I see no problems with that, but such a post, like all reference requests, should include some other specific criteria, as I list in an example request.

Comment: While a question asking for solutions are sometimes lacking context, those questions seems to be useful for the following reasons: (1) it might not be easy to find the solution using a naive google search. For example, when I search Dummit & Foote solution, I got only two meaningful results and one of them is from [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/458447/solution-manual-for-chapters-13-and-14-dummit-foote) (not sure why, but the link provided in that MSE cannot be found in my search). Moreover, if the solution cannot be found via google search, MSE is probably the best place...

Comment: to ask since this is where math-people gather. (2) this is rare, but sometimes those questions is an opportunity for the author to voice their opinion, for example, John Lee posted an answer to this [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/750163/lee-introduction-to-smooth-manifolds-solutions/750821#750821) his opinion about a complete solution guide for his popular book. I definitely think that's a very informative answer that is valuable to this site.

Answer (score 4):

Upvote this answer if you think that questions soliciting solutions manuals should be explicitly prohibited under [reference-request](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request). In the future, questions soliciting solutions manuals should be closed as off-topic. The tag wiki will be edited to reflect this rule.

Answer (score 2):

Upvote this answer if you think that questions soliciting solutions manuals should be allowed under [reference-request](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request). In this case, no change will be made to the tag wiki.